# Why oval can't be drawn?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

Im trying to understand a Paint Graphics, but my oval can't be drawn. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and oval is not drawing?
Where did I make a mistake?

Main class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Frame frame = new Frame();

        }
    });
}
```

Frame class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static Grafika grafika;

public Frame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
    grafika = new Grafika();

    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    // frame.addKeyListener(this);
    frame.add(grafika);
}
}
```

And last Grafic class:

```
public class Grafika extends JComponent {

int x = 200;
int y = 200;

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D oval = (Graphics2D) g;
    oval.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    oval.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
    oval.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

}
}
```

Comment: If your Frame class extends JFrame, why do you create a new JFrame in the Frame constructor? You already ARE a JFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues, but the biggest is that you're using a null layout on your JFrame, and then adding a JComponent whose preferred size and size are both 0,0. So while you're adding your Grafika to the JFrame, it doesn't have a chance of being displayed.

Suggestions:

- Never use `null` layout, except in very specific exceptional circumstances.
- Give your Grafika component a preferred size, best by overriding `getPreferredSize()`, but at this stage, I think that it would be OK to call `setPreferredSize(...)` on it.
- Add it to the JFrame, `pack()` the JFrame and then lastly, only after all components have been added to the JFrame, make it visible.

Also

- You should be overriding paintComponent not paint
- You should call the super painting method within your override.
- Always use the `@Override` annotation when you *think* that you're overriding a parent method. You could be wrong, and you want the compiler to tell you.
- Set the RenderingHints ***before*** drawing. Else the hints will have no effect on the drawing.
- Avoid giving your classes names that clash with the names of core Java classes, such as `Frame`. This will potentially confuse others and your future self.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGrafika extends JComponent {
    private static final int PREF_W = 500;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final Color OVAL_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private int ovalX = 200;
    private int ovalY = 200;
    private int ovalWidth = 100;
    private int ovalHeight = 100;

    public MyGrafika() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(OVAL_COLOR);
        g2.fillOval(ovalX, ovalY, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyGrafika mainPanel = new MyGrafika();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGrafika");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Swing` you should override `paintComponent` and not `paint`, you should also take care using null layout. But the point is that you should have added your `Grafika` component before making the frame visible:

```
frame.add(grafika);
frame.setVisible(true);
//    frame.setLayout(null); REMOVE THIS!
```

If you really need to add a component after the frame has been made visible, then you should call revalidate+repaint on the frame or the panel that contains the added component:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
//    frame.setLayout(null); REMOVE THIS!
frame.add(grafika);
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```